# How do I create a separate class for my navigation bar list and my list in the body?

Tags: html, css, list, navigation

I'm trying to style a list in my body paragraph, but it conflicts with the list in my navigation bar and I am unsure of how to give them 2 separate classes. I've tried giving a class to the list in my body paragraph but whether I give it to all the list tags, I can't seem to make it work.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: Montserrat;
  background-size: 120%;
}

nav {
  background: #676156;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

nav ul {
  word-spacing: 40px;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 80px;
  margin: 0 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}

nav ul li a {
  color: white;
  font-size: 35px;
  padding: 10px 13px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: inline-block;
}

a:hover {
  background: #877d6a;
  transition: .5s;
}

h2 {
  color: #000000;
  font-family: Montserrat;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #bcbcbc;
  margin: 20px 0;
  margin-left: 10px;
  font-size: 50px;
}

li {
  font-size: 25px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  list-style: none;
}

li:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

li:before {
  content: "\2022";
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title> Villa Tari</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href=../facilities.css />
</head>

<body>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a class="active" href="../index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="overview.html">Overview</a></li>
      <li><a href="location.html">Location</a></li>
      <li><a href="facilities.html">Facilities</a></li>
      <li><a href="facilities.html">Gallery</a></li>
      <li><a href="booking.html">Booking</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <h2> Facilities </h2>

  <ul>
    <li>3 bedrooms with ensuite bathrooms</li>
    <li>Swimming pool with pool deck</li>
    <li>Fully equipped Kitchen including: Microwave, coffee maker, oven, fridge </li>
    <li>Cable TV and DVD</li>
    <li>Free Wifi</li>
    <li>Air conditioning in all bedrooms</li>
    <li>Free Water and Coffee</li>
    <li>Canggu Club complimentary membership during your stay (tennis, squash, large Swimming pool, club lounge, restaurants, fitness/wellness</li>
    <li>Car park for up to three cars</li>
    <li>Staff on site for daily cleaning and support if required</li>
    <li>Pick up / drop off from airport can be provided upon request free of charge</li>
    <li>Motorcycle/car rental upon request</li>
    <li>Laundry service upon request /laundry machine available for self washing</li>
  </ul>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I can't understand where is the problem. add a class to che second ul and use it in your css. I'll suggest to read something about [css specifity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

Comment: How would I add that class to li:not(:last-child) and li:before rather than just the li tag.

Comment: if you want to add it only to the second ul list, add a class to ul tag and then use .your-class li:not(:last-child)